# Ruby Superclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, superclass

The program below is an attempt to take in an American president, and French President's age, and name. The catch is that the French president says "bein sur" afterward calling his name, age and citizenship (not my idea). I'm having trouble with the French president's catchphrase. Here's my code

```
class President
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
     @name = name 
     @age = age
  end 

  def name=(name) # setter
   @name = name
  end

  def name # getter
   @name
  end

  def age=(age)
   @age = age
  end

  def age
   @age
  end
end

class FrancePresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "La France"
  end 

  def initialize(name, age)
    super(name)
    super(age)
  end 

  def catchphrase
    "bein sur"
  end

end

class UnitedStatesPresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "The Unites States of America"
  end
end
```

The instance method I have for his catch phrase is the last attempt out of many to get this guy to say this phrase, but it's incomplete, I think I'm supposed to define calls to the super class for getting his name and age, but I'm unsure of how to get past this argument error.

```
ArgumentError
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
exercise.rb:4:in `initialize'

exercise.rb:32:in `initialize'

exercise_spec.rb:24:in `new'

exercise_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm new to ruby, so any hints or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `def age/def age=()` (and `name` too) are redundant because of the `attr_accessor :name, :age`  Automatically defining those other methods is exactly what `attr_accessor` accomplishes, so you don't need to define them yourself.

Comment: Oh, so `attr_accessor` is like a built in getter and setter?

Comment: The Catchphrase should read "bien sûr" :) source: https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/of%20course

Comment: @ClydeBrown Yes, it is a shorthand for defining the exact simple getters/setters you defined. If you have to do more work in the setter or getter (validation, for example) you would need to define them yourself, but `attr_accessor` produces exactly the code you included for getters/setters.

Comment: @ClydeBrown If you call `attr_accessor` on those and then call `President.new.methods`, you'l find `age, age=, name, name=` among its available instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
super(name)
super(age)
```

with this:

```
super(name, age)
```

The `initialize` method in `President` takes *two* parameters, not one.

You could even remove the arguments, and the parameters will be passed by default:

```
super
```

Better yet, just remove the entire `initalize` method in subclasses of `President`, because it is inherited.

Comment: Alternatively, omit the args `(name,age)` entirely, calling simply `super`, and the same arguments passed to the subclass initializer will be passed to the superclass.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Just realized the entire `initialize` method can be omitted in subclasses.

Comment: To August: 

The initialize method in President takes two parameters, not one. so both parameters need to be in the same super()? why?

Comment: TO Michael and August: why omit initialize in the subclass?

Comment: @ClydeBrown Because it's just like any other method. Calling `foo(1)`, then `foo(2)` is **not** equivalent to `foo(1, 2)`. You can omit `initialize` in the subclass because it is _inherited_ from the superclass. Read about inheritance [here](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex44.html)

Comment: Got past those issues. Thanks!

Comment: @ClydeBrown Don't forget to hit the accept button if this solved your problem :)